# c# console application starting Java GUI application

Tags: java, c#, javafx, process, console-application

I am trying to start a Java GUI application (JavaFX) from a C# console application like this:

```
public static void StartProcess(string workDir, string dllDir)
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("java");
    info.Arguments = @"-Djava.library.path=""" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\lib\" + dllDir + @"""" +  "-jar immersive.jar " + workDir;
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = info;
    proc.Start();
}
```

The application is started successfully, a new console window is opened, and I see debug output from the Java app. However the GUI of the Java app is missing. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Manifest File

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.8.0_05-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/opencv-2411.jar lib/resources
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: at.itm15.immersive.book.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parameter `-cp` instead of `-jar` for running your Java application:

```
java -cp immersive.jar workDir
```

Comment: Causes the java app and the c# to exit, despite ReadLine after StarProcess.

Comment: Your GUI is missing because your application doesn't have manifest. Maybe it'll help you: [link](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/create-add-manifest-jar-file)

Comment: Check your java application from command prompt. It seems it has troubles. Also check path to immersive.jar and first argument to java app (workDir).